# Why does my SuiteQL POST request work when I use Postman, but when I cURL the same code in VS Code terminal, it returns 'INVALID_LOGIN'

Tags: visual-studio, rest, postman, netsuite, suitetalk

I'm trying to use SuiteQL to query a workbook for a client implementation, but I'm having trouble getting it to work in VS Code. I downloaded the Postman environment template and collections archive from the SuiteTalk tools download page and then sent a test request. It returned a successful JSON response.  I then tried to send the same sample request using cURL in the VS Code terminal, then with node-fetch, and then using an npm library called netsuite-rest.  All of these return 401 'INVALID_LOGIN'.  Why does it work when I use Postman, but nowhere else?  Here's a sample of my cURL request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<ACCOUNT_ID>.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=5' \
--header 'prefer: transient' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: OAuth realm="<ACCOUNT_ID>",oauth_consumer_key="<CONSUMER_KEY>",oauth_token="<TOKEN>",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="<TIMESTAMP>",oauth_nonce="<NONCE>",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="<SIGNATURE>"' \
--header 'Cookie: NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING' \
--data-raw '{
    "q": "SELECT id, companyName, email, dateCreated FROM customer WHERE dateCreated >= '\''01/01/2019'\'' AND dateCreated < '\''01/01/2020'\''"
}'
```

Comment: How are you building "oauth_signature"?

Comment: --header 'prefer: transient' worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I see this is an old thread however, I myself am just getting started with NetSuite and Postman. For me, the netsuite Postman query will work fine when you get your access token and this will work for a short period of time. Eventually it will fail and at that time you need to use your refresh token to get a new access token. Then, add the fresh access token into your query authorization as a bearer token - and then the query will start working again.

Once it is actively working then there is a magic Area of postman = Code Snippet. So click on that and then notice that there is a pulldown menu of many code bases - that will display the entire code request for your query! For example you could choose nodeJS - Axios - and just copy the code and paste it in to your webpage.

The one thing you will have to remember is that the access token Will expire after a period of time and then you will have to replace the access token with a fresh one (using the refresh token).